# What is the simplest way to make a command that produces a quadratic expression?

Tags: macros

I want to have a command that accepts 1 optional argument and 3 mandatory ones.

Example:

1. `\qe{a}{b}{c}` produces ax^2+bx+c
2. `\qe[y]{-1}{0}{-c}` produces -y^2-c

How to make this command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynomial}

\begin{document}
$\polynomial{\frac12,0,-1,1}$

$\polynomial[reciprocal]{\frac12,0,-1,1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

See manual of `polynomial` for more options.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/polynomial.html

Comment: Worth also to have a look at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cool/

Comment: @Yiannis: Yes. `cool` package is rather useful for those who use special math functions heavily. However, it doesn't deal with such polinomials.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\MinusOne{-1}
\newcommand\qec[4][x]{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\def\temp{#2}
    \ifx\temp\MinusOne -\else #2\fi#1^2\fi
  \ifx\relax#3\relax\else\def\temp{#3}
    \ifx\temp\MinusOne -\else+#3\fi#1\fi
  \ifx\relax#4\relax\else+ #4\fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\qec{a}{b}{c}\\
\qec[y]{-1}{}{-c}\\
\qec[y]{-1}{}{}\\
\qec{}{1}{2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @xport: see edit. However, it makes no real sense, because it becomes more and more complecated. `+-c` and `+1x` is also not a nice output. It is easier to type it as it is ...

Comment: The only one of your test cases which actually looks right is the first.

Comment: @Ryan, edited the code

Answer (score 1):

what about what follows as a first attempt:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\qec}[4]{#1 #4^2 + #2 #4+ #3}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\qec{a}{b}{c}{y}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\qec{1}{2}{3}{p}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```